# execute sql queries in perl syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, perl

I want to connect sql server and execute sql queries
I use below Perl code

In this code i use ADO DRIVER and odledb driver are installed

code is

```
use DBI;
my $host = 'sqlservername';
my $database = 'db';
my $user = 'usr';
my $auth = 'Password';
# DBD::ADO
$dsn = "Provider=sqloledb;Trusted Connection=yes;";
$dsn .= "Server=$host;Database=$database";
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ADO:$dsn",
$user,
$auth,
{ RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1}
) || die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";

my $sql = "select col1,col2,col3 from tablename"
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
# Execute the statement
$sth->execute();
my( $id, $name, $phone_number );
$sth->bind_columns( undef, \$id, \$name, \$phone_number );
# Retrieve values from the result set
while( $sth->fetch() ) {
print "$id, $name, $phone_number\n";
}
# Close the connection
$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

error is

```
syntax error at testdbconn.pl line 16, near "my "
Execution of testdbconn.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Please me solution

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typo. You're missing semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing a semicolon in the below initialization of $sql.

```
my $sql = "select col1,col2,col3 from tablename"
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
```